# setting a named range based on offset cell text info

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Sheet named "Sales". This sheet has Column A2:A1500 with Item Names. Each of the A2 through A1500 rows has sales info on the adjoining columns per item. I have a Web API which updates the item's sales information per row and it's adjoining column with new data( always overwriting same row).

I am trying to create a code to create named ranges based on the adjoining cell's text and if a new item name is created to create a named range for the new item added.

1st. I would want to create named ranges out of each Item name per row. meaning Cell A2 text will be "ItemName1" Range, A3 text will be "ItemName2" range. this function i will need to iterate through the whole column A last row.

2nd. if the Web API created a new Itemname within column A, the api is set to create the new item name at the last known row of column A.

This is what i have so far. but i thought of the variable of the new item added and i do not have a solution for that.

```
Sub NamedRanges()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim intLstRow As Integer

intLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each rngCell In Range("B2:B" & intLstRow)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, RefersTo:=Range("Sales!$B$" & rngCell.Row)
Next
End Sub
```

I am currently getting an

> application or object defined error

at `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=`.

I do see my first cell name on `RefersTo:=Range("Sales"!$A$" & rngCell.Row)`.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Are you escaping your "" correctly?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rngCell.Offset(0, -3).Value & rngCell.Offset(0, -2).Value, _
RefersTo:=Range("Sales!$A$" & rngCell.Row)

Comment: But you can't offset - columns from A

Comment: Which columns has the values to create the name from?

Comment: Will name first row but then give me "application or object defined error"  to your question the column A or B has the same item name.

Comment: Read @QHarr's third comment.

Comment: I made some changes to the code above. Now it will run through the code for first row and create the named range. On the second Next (2nd row), I see the value pass into rngCell.offset and the RefersTo with the proper name but i get the "application or object defined error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. It uses correct syntax for concatenating the name for the named range and uses a different method for finding the last row. Your method using UsedRange can give unexpected results. I also changed name for last row to LstRow as you don't need to use [Hungarian](https://optionexplicitvba.com/2014/02/17/its-time-to-say-goodbye-to-hungarian-notation/) notation in VBA, also put as Long to avoid overflow.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NamedRanges()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim LstRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    LstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End With


For Each rngCell In Range("B2:B" & LstRow)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, RefersTo:=Range("Sales!$B$" & rngCell.Row)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It will run through the code for first row and create the named range for the first item. On the second Next (2nd row), I see the value pass into rngCell.offset and the RefersTo with the proper name but i get the "application or object defined error"

Comment: Then there is something else going on with your code. If the activesheet cell A2 has Item1 in it and A3 has Item2 in it, then the code i posted will loop and create named ranges in the Sales sheet for #cells B2 and B3.

Comment: If you have empty cells then you need to consider how to skip these (e.g. if not  isempty(rngCell) .......),  though  from prior conversations, i don' think this is the case.

Comment: Found my issue.  the syntax of name was incorrect. Thank you. when a new item is added i would need to run code again? or could i create a trigger? if so, please point to a method so i may do some due diligence.

Comment: You can have a worksheet Chang recent where the target is tested for target.column = 1 I.e. Column A and have that run your sub but you may want to find a way to only add the next item